# How to use @google-cloud/speech node.js package in angular App?

Tags: angular, npm, google-speech-api

I would like to use the node.js package "[@google-cloud/speech](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-speech)" in my angular 6 app.

From what I read on [this freecodecamp forum](https://forum.freecodecamp.org/t/can-i-use-npm-packages-directly-inside-angular-2/132935/5), I can easily use a node.js

```
package with:

import * as md5 from 'js-md5'
...
ngOnInit(){
  console.log(md5(""));
}
```

But when I try to launch the Angular App, I got a bunch of errors on compilation:

> WARNING in
>   ./node_modules/grpc/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/versioning.js
>   17:20-67 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an
>   expression
>
> WARNING in
>   ./node_modules/grpc/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/pre-binding.js
>   20:22-48 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an
>   expression
>
> WARNING in ./node_modules/grpc/src/grpc_extension.js 32:12-33 Critical
>   dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
>
> WARNING in ./node_modules/grpc/node_modules/minimatch/minimatch.js
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in
>   '\src\client\node_modules\grpc\node_modules\minimatch'
>
> WARNING in ./node_modules/minimatch/minimatch.js Module not found:
>   Error: Can't resolve 'path' in '\src\client\node_modules\minimatch'
>
> ERROR in ./node_modules/google-gax/lib/operations_client.js Module not
>   found: Error: Can't resolve './operations_client_config' in
>   '\src\client\node_modules\google-gax\lib' ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/google-gax/index.js Module not found: Error: Can't
>   resolve './package' in '\src\client\node_modules\google-gax' ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/@google-cloud/speech/src/v1/speech_client.js Module not
>   found: Error: Can't resolve './speech_client_config' in
>   '\src\client\node_modules\@google-cloud\speech\src\v1' ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/@google-cloud/speech/src/v1p1beta1/speech_client.js
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './speech_client_config' in
>   '\src\client\node_modules\@google-cloud\speech\src\v1p1beta1' ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/gtoken/node_modules/mime/index.js Module not found:
>   Error: Can't resolve './types/other' in
>   '\src\client\node_modules\gtoken\node_modules\mime' ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/gtoken/node_modules/mime/index.js Module not found:
>   Error: Can't resolve './types/standard' in
>   '\src\client\node_modules\gtoken\node_modules\mime' ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/googleauth.js Module
>   not found: Error: Can't resolve 'child_process' in
>   '\src\client\node_modules\google-auth-library\build\src\auth' ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/grpc/node_modules/detect-libc/lib/detect-libc.js Module
>   not found: Error: Can't resolve 'child_process' in
>   '\src\client\node_modules\grpc\node_modules\detect-libc\lib' ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/aws-sign2/index.js Module not found: Error: Can't
>   resolve 'crypto' in '\src\client\node_modules\aws-sign2' ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/aws4/aws4.js Module not found: Error: Can't resolve
>   'crypto' in '\src\client\node_modules\aws4' ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/ecc-jsbn/index.js Module not found: Error: Can't
>   resolve 'crypto' in '\src\client\node_modules\ecc-jsbn' ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/pemverifier.js Module not
>   found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in
>   '\src\client\node_modules\google-auth-library\build\src' ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/oauth2client.js
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in
>   '\src\client\node_modules\google-auth-library\build\src\auth' ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/google-auto-auth/index.js Module not found: Error:
>   Can't resolve 'crypto' in '\src\client\node_modules\google-auto-auth'
>   ERROR in ./node_modules/http-signature/lib/signer.js Module not found:
>   Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in
>   '\src\client\node_modules\http-signature\lib' ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/http-signature/lib/verify.js Module not found: Error:
>   Can't resolve 'crypto' in
>   '\src\client\node_modules\http-signature\lib' ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/jwa/index.js Module not found: Error: Can't resolve
>   'crypto' in '\src\client\node_modules\jwa' ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/oauth-sign/index.js Module not found: Error: Can't
>   resolve 'crypto' in '\src\client\node_modules\oauth-sign' ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/request/lib/helpers.js Module not found: Error: Can't
>   resolve 'crypto' in '\src\client\node_modules\request\lib' ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/request/lib/oauth.js Module not found: Error: Can't
>   resolve 'crypto' in '\src\client\node_modules\request\lib' ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/sshpk/lib/signature.js Module not found: Error: Can't
>   resolve 'crypto' in '\src\client\node_modules\sshpk\lib' ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/sshpk/lib/private-key.js Module not found: Error: Can't
>   resolve 'crypto' in '\src\client\node_modules\sshpk\lib' ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/sshpk/lib/dhe.js Module not found: Error: Can't resolve
>   'crypto' in '\src\client\node_modules\sshpk\lib' ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/sshpk/lib/key.js Module not found: Error: Can't resolve
>   'crypto' in '\src\client\node_modules\sshpk\lib' ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/sshpk/lib/certificate.js Module not found: Error: Can't
>   resolve 'crypto' in '\src\client\node_modules\sshpk\lib' ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/sshpk/lib/fingerprint.js Module not found: Error: Can't
>   resolve 'crypto' in '\src\client\node_modules\sshpk\lib' ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/sshpk/lib/utils.js Module not found: Error: Can't
>   resolve 'crypto' in '\src\client\node_modules\sshpk\lib' ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/sshpk/lib/identity.js Module not found: Error: Can't
>   resolve 'crypto' in '\src\client\node_modules\sshpk\lib' ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/sshpk/lib/formats/openssh-cert.js Module not found:
>   Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in
>   '\src\client\node_modules\sshpk\lib\formats' ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/sshpk/lib/formats/pem.js Module not found: Error: Can't
>   resolve 'crypto' in '\src\client\node_modules\sshpk\lib\formats' ERROR
>   in ./node_modules/sshpk/lib/formats/ssh-private.js Module not found:
>   Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in
>   '\src\client\node_modules\sshpk\lib\formats' ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/@mrmlnc/readdir-enhanced/lib/async/index.js Module not
>   found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in
>   '\src\client\node_modules\@mrmlnc\readdir-enhanced\lib\async' ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/@mrmlnc/readdir-enhanced/lib/stream/index.js Module not
>   found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in
>   '\src\client\node_modules\@mrmlnc\readdir-enhanced\lib\stream' ERROR
>   in ./node_modules/@mrmlnc/readdir-enhanced/lib/sync/fs.js Module not
>   found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in
>   '\src\client\node_modules\@mrmlnc\readdir-enhanced\lib\sync' ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/fast-glob/out/adapters/fs-stream.js Module not found:
>   Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in
>   '\src\client\node_modules\fast-glob\out\adapters' ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/fast-glob/out/adapters/fs-sync.js Module not found:
>   Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in
>   '\src\client\node_modules\fast-glob\out\adapters' ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/fs.realpath/old.js Module not found: Error: Can't
>   resolve 'fs' in '\src\client\node_modules\fs.realpath' ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/fs.realpath/index.js Module not found: Error: Can't
>   resolve 'fs' in '\src\client\node_modules\fs.realpath' ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/glob/glob.js Module not found: Error: Can't resolve
>   'fs' in '\src\client\node_modules\glob' ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/glob/sync.js Module not found: Error: Can't resolve
>   'fs' in '\src\client\node_modules\glob' ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/googleauth.js Module
>   not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in
>   '\src\client\node_modules\google-auth-library\build\src\auth' ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/google-auto-auth/index.js Module not found: Error:
>   Can't resolve 'fs' in '\src\client\node_modules\google-auto-auth'
>   ERROR in ./node_modules/google-gax/lib/grpc.js Module not found:
>   Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '\src\client\node_modules\google-gax\lib'
>   ERROR in ./node_modules/google-gax/node_modules/globby/gitignore.js
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in
>   '\src\client\node_modules\google-gax\node_modules\globby' ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/google-p12-pem/build/src/index.js Module not found:
>   Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in
>   '\src\client\node_modules\google-p12-pem\build\src' ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/google-proto-files/node_modules/globby/gitignore.js
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in
>   '\src\client\node_modules\google-proto-files\node_modules\globby'
>   ERROR in ./node_modules/grpc/index.js Module not found: Error: Can't
>   resolve 'fs' in '\src\client\node_modules\grpc' ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/grpc/node_modules/detect-libc/lib/detect-libc.js Module
>   not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in
>   '\src\client\node_modules\grpc\node_modules\detect-libc\lib' ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/grpc/node_modules/fs.realpath/old.js Module not found:
>   Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in
>   '\src\client\node_modules\grpc\node_modules\fs.realpath' ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/grpc/node_modules/fs.realpath/index.js Module not
>   found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in
>   '\src\client\node_modules\grpc\node_modules\fs.realpath' ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/grpc/node_modules/glob/sync.js Module not found: Error:
>   Can't resolve 'fs' in
>   '\src\client\node_modules\grpc\node_modules\glob' ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/grpc/node_modules/glob/glob.js Module not found: Error:
>   Can't resolve 'fs' in
>   '\src\client\node_modules\grpc\node_modules\glob' ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/grpc/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/pre-binding.js
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in
>   '\src\client\node_modules\grpc\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\lib' ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/grpc/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/napi.js Module
>   not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in
>   '\src\client\node_modules\grpc\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\lib\util'
>   ERROR in ./node_modules/grpc/node_modules/rimraf/rimraf.js Module not
>   found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in
>   '\src\client\node_modules\grpc\node_modules\rimraf' ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/grpc/src/grpc_extension.js Module not found: Error:
>   Can't resolve 'fs' in '\src\client\node_modules\grpc\src' ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/gtoken/build/src/index.js Module not found: Error:
>   Can't resolve 'fs' in '\src\client\node_modules\gtoken\build\src'
>   ERROR in ./node_modules/path-type/index.js Module not found: Error:
>   Can't resolve 'fs' in '\src\client\node_modules\path-type' ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/request/lib/har.js Module not found: Error: Can't
>   resolve 'fs' in '\src\client\node_modules\request\lib' ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/snapdragon/lib/source-maps.js Module not found: Error:
>   Can't resolve 'fs' in '\src\client\node_modules\snapdragon\lib' ERROR
>   in ./node_modules/forever-agent/index.js Module not found: Error:
>   Can't resolve 'http' in '\src\client\node_modules\forever-agent' ERROR
>   in ./node_modules/http-signature/lib/signer.js Module not found:
>   Error: Can't resolve 'http' in
>   '\src\client\node_modules\http-signature\lib' ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/request/request.js Module not found: Error: Can't
>   resolve 'http' in '\src\client\node_modules\request' ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/tunnel-agent/index.js Module not found: Error: Can't
>   resolve 'http' in '\src\client\node_modules\tunnel-agent' ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/forever-agent/index.js Module not found: Error: Can't
>   resolve 'https' in '\src\client\node_modules\forever-agent' ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/request/request.js Module not found: Error: Can't
>   resolve 'https' in '\src\client\node_modules\request' ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/tunnel-agent/index.js Module not found: Error: Can't
>   resolve 'https' in '\src\client\node_modules\tunnel-agent' ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/forever-agent/index.js Module not found: Error: Can't
>   resolve 'net' in '\src\client\node_modules\forever-agent' ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/tough-cookie/lib/cookie.js Module not found: Error:
>   Can't resolve 'net' in '\src\client\node_modules\tough-cookie\lib'
>   ERROR in ./node_modules/tunnel-agent/index.js Module not found: Error:
>   Can't resolve 'net' in '\src\client\node_modules\tunnel-agent' ERROR
>   in ./node_modules/glob-parent/index.js Module not found: Error: Can't
>   resolve 'os' in '\src\client\node_modules\glob-parent' ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/googleauth.js Module
>   not found: Error: Can't resolve 'os' in
>   '\src\client\node_modules\google-auth-library\build\src\auth' ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/grpc/node_modules/detect-libc/lib/detect-libc.js Module
>   not found: Error: Can't resolve 'os' in
>   '\src\client\node_modules\grpc\node_modules\detect-libc\lib' ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/@google-cloud/speech/src/v1/speech_client.js Module not
>   found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in
>   '\src\client\node_modules\@google-cloud\speech\src\v1' ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/@google-cloud/speech/src/v1p1beta1/speech_client.js
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in
>   '\src\client\node_modules\@google-cloud\speech\src\v1p1beta1' ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/@mrmlnc/readdir-enhanced/lib/normalize-options.js
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in
>   '\src\client\node_modules\@mrmlnc\readdir-enhanced\lib' ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/@mrmlnc/readdir-enhanced/lib/directory-reader.js Module
>   not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in
>   '\src\client\node_modules\@mrmlnc\readdir-enhanced\lib' ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/dir-glob/index.js Module not found: Error: Can't
>   resolve 'path' in '\src\client\node_modules\dir-glob' ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/fast-glob/out/adapters/fs.js Module not found: Error:
>   Can't resolve 'path' in
>   '\src\client\node_modules\fast-glob\out\adapters' ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/fast-glob/out/providers/reader.js Module not found:
>   Error: Can't resolve 'path' in
>   '\src\client\node_modules\fast-glob\out\providers' ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/fast-glob/out/utils/pattern.js Module not found: Error:
>   Can't resolve 'path' in '\src\client\node_modules\fast-glob\out\utils'
>   ERROR in ./node_modules/fast-glob/out/utils/path.js Module not found:
>   Error: Can't resolve 'path' in
>   '\src\client\node_modules\fast-glob\out\utils' ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/fs.realpath/old.js Module not found: Error: Can't
>   resolve 'path' in '\src\client\node_modules\fs.realpath' ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/glob/sync.js Module not found: Error: Can't resolve
>   'path' in '\src\client\node_modules\glob' ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/glob/glob.js Module not found: Error: Can't resolve
>   'path' in '\src\client\node_modules\glob' ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/glob/common.js Module not found: Error: Can't resolve
>   'path' in '\src\client\node_modules\glob' ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/glob-parent/index.js Module not found: Error: Can't
>   resolve 'path' in '\src\client\node_modules\glob-parent' ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/googleauth.js Module
>   not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in
>   '\src\client\node_modules\google-auth-library\build\src\auth' ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/google-auto-auth/index.js Module not found: Error:
>   Can't resolve 'path' in '\src\client\node_modules\google-auto-auth'
>   ERROR in ./node_modules/google-gax/lib/grpc.js Module not found:
>   Error: Can't resolve 'path' in
>   '\src\client\node_modules\google-gax\lib' ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/google-gax/node_modules/globby/gitignore.js Module not
>   found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in
>   '\src\client\node_modules\google-gax\node_modules\globby' ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/google-proto-files/load.js Module not found: Error:
>   Can't resolve 'path' in '\src\client\node_modules\google-proto-files'
>   ERROR in ./node_modules/google-proto-files/index.js Module not found:
>   Error: Can't resolve 'path' in
>   '\src\client\node_modules\google-proto-files' ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/google-proto-files/node_modules/globby/gitignore.js
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in
>   '\src\client\node_modules\google-proto-files\node_modules\globby'
>   ERROR in ./node_modules/grpc/index.js Module not found: Error: Can't
>   resolve 'path' in '\src\client\node_modules\grpc' ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/grpc/node_modules/fs.realpath/old.js Module not found:
>   Error: Can't resolve 'path' in
>   '\src\client\node_modules\grpc\node_modules\fs.realpath' ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/grpc/node_modules/glob/glob.js Module not found: Error:
>   Can't resolve 'path' in
>   '\src\client\node_modules\grpc\node_modules\glob' ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/grpc/node_modules/glob/common.js Module not found:
>   Error: Can't resolve 'path' in
>   '\src\client\node_modules\grpc\node_modules\glob' ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/grpc/node_modules/glob/sync.js Module not found: Error:
>   Can't resolve 'path' in
>   '\src\client\node_modules\grpc\node_modules\glob' ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/grpc/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/pre-binding.js
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in
>   '\src\client\node_modules\grpc\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\lib' ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/grpc/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/versioning.js
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in
>   '\src\client\node_modules\grpc\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\lib\util'
>   ERROR in ./node_modules/grpc/node_modules/rimraf/rimraf.js Module not
>   found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in
>   '\src\client\node_modules\grpc\node_modules\rimraf' ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/grpc/src/grpc_extension.js Module not found: Error:
>   Can't resolve 'path' in '\src\client\node_modules\grpc\src' ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/micromatch/lib/utils.js Module not found: Error: Can't
>   resolve 'path' in '\src\client\node_modules\micromatch\lib' ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/mime-types/index.js Module not found: Error: Can't
>   resolve 'path' in '\src\client\node_modules\mime-types' ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/nanomatch/lib/utils.js Module not found: Error: Can't
>   resolve 'path' in '\src\client\node_modules\nanomatch\lib' ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/path-dirname/index.js Module not found: Error: Can't
>   resolve 'path' in '\src\client\node_modules\path-dirname' ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/snapdragon/lib/source-maps.js Module not found: Error:
>   Can't resolve 'path' in '\src\client\node_modules\snapdragon\lib'
>   ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/@mrmlnc/readdir-enhanced/lib/directory-reader.js Module
>   not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in
>   '\src\client\node_modules\@mrmlnc\readdir-enhanced\lib' ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/assert-plus/assert.js Module not found: Error: Can't
>   resolve 'stream' in '\src\client\node_modules\assert-plus' ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/combined-stream/lib/combined_stream.js Module not
>   found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in
>   '\src\client\node_modules\combined-stream\lib' ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/delayed-stream/lib/delayed_stream.js Module not found:
>   Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in
>   '\src\client\node_modules\delayed-stream\lib' ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/fast-glob/out/adapters/fs-stream.js Module not found:
>   Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in
>   '\src\client\node_modules\fast-glob\out\adapters' ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/fast-glob/out/providers/reader-stream.js Module not
>   found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in
>   '\src\client\node_modules\fast-glob\out\providers' ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/oauth2client.js
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in
>   '\src\client\node_modules\google-auth-library\build\src\auth' ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/grpc/src/client.js Module not found: Error: Can't
>   resolve 'stream' in '\src\client\node_modules\grpc\src' ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/grpc/src/server.js Module not found: Error: Can't
>   resolve 'stream' in '\src\client\node_modules\grpc\src' ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/isstream/isstream.js Module not found: Error: Can't
>   resolve 'stream' in '\src\client\node_modules\isstream' ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/jws/lib/sign-stream.js Module not found: Error: Can't
>   resolve 'stream' in '\src\client\node_modules\jws\lib' ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/jws/lib/verify-stream.js Module not found: Error: Can't
>   resolve 'stream' in '\src\client\node_modules\jws\lib' ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/jws/lib/data-stream.js Module not found: Error: Can't
>   resolve 'stream' in '\src\client\node_modules\jws\lib' ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/merge2/index.js Module not found: Error: Can't resolve
>   'stream' in '\src\client\node_modules\merge2' ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/request/request.js Module not found: Error: Can't
>   resolve 'stream' in '\src\client\node_modules\request' ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/sshpk/lib/ed-compat.js Module not found: Error: Can't
>   resolve 'stream' in '\src\client\node_modules\sshpk\lib' ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/stringstream/stringstream.js Module not found: Error:
>   Can't resolve 'stream' in '\src\client\node_modules\stringstream'
>   ERROR in ./node_modules/google-gax/lib/api_callable.js Module not
>   found: Error: Can't resolve 'timers' in
>   '\src\client\node_modules\google-gax\lib' ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/forever-agent/index.js Module not found: Error: Can't
>   resolve 'tls' in '\src\client\node_modules\forever-agent' ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/tunnel-agent/index.js Module not found: Error: Can't
>   resolve 'tls' in '\src\client\node_modules\tunnel-agent' ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/request/request.js Module not found: Error: Can't
>   resolve 'zlib' in '\src\client\node_modules\request'

*(if you know a way to display all theses errors with a scrollbar on stackoverflow, please let me know in comments, I will update it)*

Which is the best way to easily use the @google-cloud/speech node.js package in my Angular App?

Comment: It's discussed here: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9827#issuecomment-369647555

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
If I understand correctly the answer of clydin. 
For this error for exemple: Error: Can't resolve './operations_client_config' in '\src\client\node_modules\google-gax\lib' , in tsconfig.json, I need to add: 
    "paths": {
      "./operations_client_config": [ "../node_modules/google-gax/lib" ],
    }
But the error is still therewhen I build the app.
Did I miss something?